# Machine specific secure local storage for desktop app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need machine specific secure local storage for desktop app created with WPF. And i think about SQL Server CE as a solution, but may some one knows better way to implement functionality which i need. Any suggestions or advices?

Comment: Put a password on your SQL CE database and store the password with [DPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_API).

Comment: This is the way i did it now, but i want to know is any other ways to do something like this

Comment: How much are you storing, one string, or a large list of information?

Comment: It will be many short text pieces in couple tables. At this moment serialized data structure has size about 60 mb.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pinvoke and **[CryptProtectData/CryptUnprotectData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** to encrypt/decrypt and store it anywhere. The data cannot be successfully locked to a particular machine/computer combo by choosing suitable options.

The CryptProtectData function performs encryption on the data in a DATA_BLOB structure. Typically, only a user with the same logon credential as the user who encrypted the data can decrypt the data. In addition, the encryption and decryption usually must be done on the same computer.

Comment: [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata) is the .NET wrapper for that class, however it does not expose the `szDataDescr` attribute if you need that for interop with other apps that use the native API.

Comment: Working with data should not take much RAM, so SQL like technology is preferred. The app should be able to make a request to take a part of data. The speed is one of the critical parametrs.

Answer (score 0):

What about SQLite? Apps like firefox use it. Not quite familiar with the security standards in SQlite, but im pretty sure that it has this feature.
[SQLite connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite) and their
[Official site](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Comment: I will think about it. Thanks.

Comment: glad to help, there is even a .net connector in the download area in the official page.